# Spring Boot, syslog & log4j2 log

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j2

I want to send a singular log message to our external syslog server but don't want to use log4j2, instead is it possible to just send a plain TCP message using something like java.net & java.io?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried to just send a standard message using Socket but I need to add some key value pairs such as logFormat & logType

Comment: Check [RFC 5424](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5424#section-6) for a modern syslog format.

Comment: Do you know of any good java examples? We know the format we need to use, but the question was more for how to do it without adding a log4j2 config to our spring boot project

Comment: Log4j 2.x **is** an example: check [`SyslogLayout`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/3042e80fc6624e410925e4a264acddad92cc1541/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/layout/SyslogLayout.java#L145) or [`Rfc5424Layout`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/3042e80fc6624e410925e4a264acddad92cc1541/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/layout/Rfc5424Layout.java#L270).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at this project, it might solve your problem. Good Luck!

https://github.com/CloudBees-community/syslog-java-client

Comment: Is it possible to do without using CloudBees? I just need to add the key value pairs for type of log message